# Does "trade understandings" and "ambitions falter" sound incoherent?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> There is a growing sense of disorder and fragmentation in the world as trade understandings and ambitions falter

Does "trade understandings" and "ambitions falter" sound incoherent or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Rich in metaphor perhaps but not incoherent!

Comment: Ambition can falter, but understanding? Once an understanding is reached, can it lose its footing or confidence?

Comment: One's understanding of something can indeed falter if something happens that defies said understanding.